# want to create a subcollection in document in firebase when user sign up to app in react native its children subcollection created

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

want to add a subcollection when the user signs up to the app a subcollection is created to its document which contains its children.
here is my code:

```
    try {
    await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(currentUser.uid)
      .set({
        email: currentUser.email,
        lastName: lastName,
        firstName: firstName,
        
      }).collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).collection("recipient").add({name:"test", age:"25" }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data.id);
        console.log("Document has added")
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    
  } catch (err) {
    alert("There is something wrong!!!!" + err.message.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is linked second add document to sub-collection because the first promise does not return the document reference but a sort of information about how long operation was taken. The right approach will be the following:

```
async function addUser(id, user) {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const users = db.collection('users')

    try {
      const result = await users.doc(id).set(user)
      return result

    } catch (e) {

      console.log("addUser: ", e)
      return null
    }
    
}

async function getUserRef(id) {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const users = db.collection('users')
   
    try {
      const docSnapshot = await users.doc(id).get()
      return docSnapshot.ref

    } catch (e) {

      console.log("getUserRef: ", e)
      return null
    }
}

try {
   const user = {
       email: currentUser.email,
       lastName: lastName,
       firstName: firstName,
   }
   const result = await addUser(id, user);
   const ref = await getUserRef(id)
   await ref.collection("recipient").add({name:"test", age:"25" })
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```